# WebView in AsyncTask doInBackground method?

Tags: android, performance, webview, android-intentservice

I'm using a WebView that injects some JS code on a page. This webview has a "domino effect", like:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient{
  ...
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains("http://A")){
        view.loadUrl("javascript: window.location.assign('http://B');")
    } else if(url.contains("http://B"){
        //do another stuff
    }
  ...
});
```

And it takes about 10~15 seconds. I'm currently doing this directly on Activity, but **i'm not satisfied with it's performance**. And more, if user minimizes the application during the process, it stops from working.

Now **i'm trying to doInBackground()**, but i can't neither instantiate a WebView on a non UI thread or call loadUrl() on a received WebView (from AsyncTask<> parameter). What can i do ?

**Should I do all this work with a IntentService ?**

**EDIT:**  I'm injecting JS to return an ArrayList. I'm using webview only to parse the webpage and get what i want.

Thanks !

Comment: A View component is supposed to be drawn on UI thread only

Comment: Are you saying you're not satisfied with the speed at which the WebView opens after you create the client and pass it to the WebView?

Comment: No.. I wasnt clear.. I'm injecting JS to return an ArrayList. I'm using webview only to parse the webpage and get what i want ^^

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update your UI from background thread.
 Use

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                // Update your UI

            }
        });
```

If it takes delay, use `ProgressDialog` and alert the user that page is being loaded.

Comment: How to send variable from doInBackground  to webview from inside runOnUithread ?i tried following but didn't work! mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyFunction(" + sb.toString() + ")");